# $\{n_k\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ where $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}<\infty,\space \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_{n_k}}=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence $\{n_k\}$ of positive integers such that
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}<\infty,\space \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_{n_k}}=\infty\space$$

Comment: But $\{n_{n_k}\}\in\{n_k\}$...

Comment: Perhaps you meant the opposite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I believe the same as you; in which case a possible example (for OP) is $n_k=1/k^2$.

Comment: Hey, I'm not the one asking the question. Just asking the OP. =)

Comment: @OlivierOloa What's the point of stressing the exercise is trivial?

Comment: I thought you have found it trivial as it is, then you suggested to reverse the inequality, but the other one is not so difficult too. Just that...

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** possible since
$$
\left\{n_{n_k}, k \in \mathbb{N}^*\right\} \subset \left\{n_k, k \in \mathbb{N}^*\right\}
$$ and the terms are non negative:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_{n_k}}\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}.
$$